# How do I explode the Tags attribute in Concrete5 value into an array?

Tags: php, attributes, tags, concrete5-5.7

I get the values of my Tags attribute and try to explode them into an array using the PHP `explode` function:

```
$test = explode(' ', $p->getCollectionAttributeValue($atHandle));
print_r($test);
```

When I echo out the value, it seems to be delimited by a space, but when I try to explode the value using space as the delimiter it fails to separate the values.

Any thoughts on what delimiter is being used for tags?

Comment: It appears that tags should already be an array (no need to explode): http://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/working-with-pages/getting-data-about-a-page

Comment: hmmm weird, if it is an array, I get an error when I try to implode the array stating "Invalid Argument Passed".

Comment: @Random, apologies for that. I've updated the code. But still the same problem.

Comment: ahhh, the value for getCollectionAttributeValue is actually and Object, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

The function getCollectionAttributeValue('tags') actually returns an object instead of an array.